# Process to change Rancher Access Control

Tags: rancher

We've set up a Rancher system with 'Local Authentication'. Is there a way to change 'Access Control' to something else?

I think disabling 'Access Control' and then enabling it again with another option could work, but I'm afraid to try in case it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one auth provider on at a time so yes disable and then enable a new one.  You will need to re-setup all the membership mapping of users to environments since the existing ones will have no meaning anymore.